# Get Common Key values in Json Format Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list with following values where each value is dict;
so basically its a list with values as dictionary

```
    {'channel_key': 'AMZ', 'channel_desc': 'amazon UK', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-01', 'price': '10'}]}
    {'channel_key': 'ebay_us', 'channel_desc': 'ebay US', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-01', 'price': '10'}]}
    {'channel_key': 'tar', 'channel_desc': 'target', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-01', 'price': '10'}]}
    {'channel_key': 'AMZ', 'channel_desc': 'amazon UK', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-02', 'price': '100'}]}
    {'channel_key': 'ebay_us', 'channel_desc': 'ebay US', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-02', 'price': '30'}]}
    {'channel_key': 'tar', 'channel_desc': 'target', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-02', 'price': '20'}]}
{'channel_key': 'alibaba', 'channel_desc': 'Alibaba', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-02', 'price': '30'}]}
```

What I am trying to do is if channel_key matches, then append channel_value field.
For e.g
Channel_key 'AMZ' is present twice, so its channel_value will become as follows;

```
'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-01', 'price': '10'},{'date': '2020-03-02', 'price': '100'}]
```

similary for tar.

Expected Output will be something like this:

```
    {'channel_key': 'AMZ', 'channel_desc': 'amazon UK', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-01', 'price': '10'},{'date': '2020-03-02', 'price': '100'}]}
    {'channel_key': 'ebay_us', 'channel_desc': 'ebay US', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-01', 'price': '10'},{'date': '2020-03-02', 'price': '30'}]}
    {'channel_key': 'tar', 'channel_desc': 'target', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-01', 'price': '10'},{'date': '2020-03-02', 'price': '20'}]}
{'channel_key': 'alibaba', 'channel_desc': 'Alibaba', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-02', 'price': '30'}]}
```

Comment: What should be the complete output? A shorter list with one element for AMZ, one for ebay_us, etc.?

Comment: @Roy2012 I have modified my question

Comment: Thanks. I see you have an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```py
def convert(t):
    d = {}
    for x in t:
        channel_key = x['channel_key']
        if channel_key in d:
            d[channel_key]['channel_value'].extend(x['channel_value'])
        else:
            d[channel_key] = x
    return list(d.values())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = [
        {'channel_key': 'AMZ', 'channel_desc': 'amazon UK', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-01', 'price': '10'}]},
        {'channel_key': 'ebay_us', 'channel_desc': 'ebay US', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-01', 'price': '10'}]},
        {'channel_key': 'tar', 'channel_desc': 'target', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-01', 'price': '10'}]},
        {'channel_key': 'AMZ', 'channel_desc': 'amazon UK', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-02', 'price': '100'}]},
        {'channel_key': 'ebay_us', 'channel_desc': 'ebay US', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-02', 'price': '30'}]},
        {'channel_key': 'tar', 'channel_desc': 'target', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-02', 'price': '20'}]},
        {'channel_key': 'alibaba', 'channel_desc': 'Alibaba', 'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-02', 'price': '30'}]}
    ]

    converted_t = convert(t)

    from pprint import pprint
    pprint(converted_t)
```

which prints

```
[{'channel_desc': 'amazon UK',
  'channel_key': 'AMZ',
  'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-01', 'price': '10'},
                    {'date': '2020-03-02', 'price': '100'}]},
 {'channel_desc': 'ebay US',
  'channel_key': 'ebay_us',
  'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-01', 'price': '10'},
                    {'date': '2020-03-02', 'price': '30'}]},
 {'channel_desc': 'target',
  'channel_key': 'tar',
  'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-01', 'price': '10'},
                    {'date': '2020-03-02', 'price': '20'}]},
 {'channel_desc': 'Alibaba',
  'channel_key': 'alibaba',
  'channel_value': [{'date': '2020-03-02', 'price': '30'}]}]
```